# Running a CustomBuildStep in a WIX project file (MsBuild)

Tags: wix

Visual Studio 2015.
MsBuild.
Wix ToolSet v3.10

This is a sanity check.
I am trying to run a CustomBuildStep from within a WIX .wixproj file via MsBuild.

I am very familiar with Visual Studio 2015 .vcxproj's and run CustomBuildSteps in almost all of my projects.

I added a CustomBuildStep to one of my .wixproj files but when I run it via MsBuild the CustomBuildStep never fires. I am 100% positive that I have the

Does anyone know if a CustomBuildStep is not valid within a WIX project file?

Has anyone successfully gotten a CustomBuildStep to work in a WIX project?

Thanks.